# Prove that, up to isomorphism, there are only finitely many groups of size n.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I thought i understood the term "up to isomorphism" but in this case it seems not. Surely if your group elements are fixed there is only one possible group?

[image]

[image]

Comment: note that there are different groups with the same number of elements. for example: $Z4$ and $Z2*Z2$. these to groups are not isomprphic because there is no element from order 4 in $Z2*Z2$

Comment: The name of the group elements don't have to have anything to do with the structure. For example, consider the cyclic group of order 4 and the Klein 4 group. Both are groups with 4 elements in them, and you may as well call them 1-2-3-4 or a-b-c-d. However, what is important is the relationship between the elements, which is really what determines a group.

Comment: Ok, I understand that but wouldn't that make "up to isomorphism" redundant in this case?

Comment: I'll give a general example: Consider the group of integers modulo 2. This is the group {0,1} under the addition operation. Write down the Cayley table for this group. Now consider the group {-1,1} under multiplication. Write down the Cayley table for this group. If you replace all instances of 1 with 0 and all instances of -1 with 1 in the second table, how does this compare to the first? This act of replacement is the same thing as writing a group isomorphism. In general, the Cayley table completely determines the group structure, and there are only finitely many entries in such a table...

Comment: Thanks aaaaalot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the question means is, colloquially speaking, is that there are only finitely many *different* groups of size $n$. But if you put it that way, the statement is technically wrong. For example, there are already *very* many groups of size $n$. Here are countably many $$
  \mathcal{G}_n := (G_n,\circ_n) \text{ where } G_n = {n}, \circ_n = {((n,n),n)} \text{.}
$$
In plain english this says that there's one group of size $1$ whose (single) element is $1$, another one whose single element is $2$, a third one whose single element is $3$ and so on. In  the group whose single element is $n$, the group operation $\circ$ is defined as $n\circ n = n$, i.e. the single element is the identity element, as it must be.

This is silly of course - all those groups are obviously the same - we just renamed the element.

So what *you* are supposed to answer is, are there infinitely many groups which differ by *more* than just the named of their elements?